# Can a question marked as Duplicate still be voted on?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, voting

If I understand correctly, a question marked as Duplicate is a closed question. If someone had the link to a question like this could they still vote on it?

Comment: *if someone had the link to a question*. You know you can [search for closed as duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3A1&searchOn=3), right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can vote on duplicates or any closed questions. It’s only locked or deleted posts that can’t be voted on (none of these categories are mutually exclusive though).

In the same way that you can downvote a closed question for not being helpful, you can upvote a closed question that you found helpful. (Some duplicates have much better wording than the question they’re closed against.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, closed questions can still be voted and commented on as long as they're not deleted or locked.

However, they cannot be answered.